# BlackBerry BrowserField problem on 9800

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

I'm using 5.0 field2.BrowserField as in-app browser, but on 9800 simulator page isn't displayed. (tested on SimPackage-6.0.0.246_9800-ATT,SimPackage-6.0.0.141_9800)

```
BrowserField browser = new BrowserField();
add(browser); 
browser.requestContent("http://www.blackberry.com" + ";deviceside=true");
```

what is problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue with the Browser Field on Simulator for the 9800 - 9850 devices. I have noted however, if you install the your app unto the simulator from a .cod file instead of loading it via IDE, the browser field will load the required page correctly, without issue. However, the browser field may still misbehaves on a real device, it does not render links embedded into the page correctly on my app for an example.

Answer (score 0):

for simulator no need to add parameter just use http://www.blackberry.com
make sure you run the simulator with MDS simulator